# spring with quartz.properties

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am trying to store the quartz scheduled job in the database by using postgreSQL.

The database name is "testdb" and the schema is "testschema". I have the following quartz.properties. I have a following quartz.properties, but I am getting this error message "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "quartz_triggers" does not exist".

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = quartz_

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = postgres
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = welcome123
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections  10
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you must run the installation script that creates the quartz tables in your database.

The files are available in the full quartz jar file (/docs/dbTables)

Here is the documentation: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09

M.